# How to get the response ( success or failure) while sending an html mail in perl

Tags: perl

Following is my code for sending an html Email in perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP ();
use Email::Simple ();
use Email::Simple::Creator ();
use Email::MIME::CreateHTML;


my $smtpserver = 'xxx.xxx.xx';
my $smtpport = 25;
my $smtpuser   = 'xxx@test.com';
my $smtppassword = 'xxxx';

my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new({
  host => $smtpserver,
  port => $smtpport,
  sasl_username => $smtpuser,
  sasl_password => $smtppassword,
});


my $html ="<div>Success</div>";
my $plain_text ="plain text";

my $email = Email::MIME->create_html(
        header => [
                From => 'test@lintotest.com',
                To => 'linodavis@gmailcom',
                Subject => 'Test Mail',
        ],
        body => $html,
        text_body => $plain_text
);

sendmail($email, { transport => $transport });
```

Its working fine.Now i need to find the response of mail sending.

for that i modified the code as

```
eval {
sendmail($email, { transport => $transport });    # this is try catch method
};
if ($@) {
        # where $@ is a object of Email::Sender::Failure
    print $@->message;
    print"\n".$@->code ;

}else{
 print "success";
}
```

Now let me know, is there any better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Two things that would improve your code.

Firstly, it's always good practice to take a copy of `$@` as soon as possible (in case something that you do while handling the error changes the value of `$@`).

```
if (my $e = $@) {
    print $e->message;
    print"\n" . $e->code;
}
```

Secondly, it's also worth considering a module like [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/Try%3a%3aTiny) which will make your exception handling code look a bit nicer.

```
try {
    sendmail($email, { transport => $transport });
} catch {
    # Exception is in $_
    print $_->message;
    print"\n" . $_->code;
}
```